# Memory error converting large RGB image to grayscale

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, grayscale

I am trying to load original color fundus images in python for some learning project. These are RGB images of sizes approx. 4000*2000*3. I want to convert each image to grayscale before sending them for training into my model. For this, I've tried the following 2 approaches:

**Method 1:**

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

def load_images(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        gray = rgb2gray(img)
        images.append(gray)
    return images
```

**Method 2:**

```
from PIL import Image

def load_images(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        gray = img.convert('L')
        images.append(gray)
    return images
```

In both the methods, I get the same `Memory Error` at lines `gray = rgb2gray(img)` and `gray = img.convert('L')` respectively.

Is there any way I can convert such large images to grayscale one at a time and store it as a list?

Comment: Could you try Method 2 again, but on just one image to first determine whether convert actually works

Comment: The problem may be the result of trying to keep all the converted images in memory at the same time (i.e. the `images` list getting too big)—as opposed it being caused by trying to convert one of them. Determining **that** via @Attaque's suggestion would be worthwhile because then you would know the actual cause of the error.

Comment: If the problem just the result of trying to convert the large image, then yes, something like that could be worked around via `PIL` by first subdividing (cropping) the original image into a group of smaller ones, processing each one of those separately, and then combining them back together to create the final result.

Comment: Yes it runs for a few images, but when I execute it for all my 413 training images and store all grayscale images in a list, my system hangs up and I get memory error.

Comment: @Prachi in that case, have your function work on only a single image, and call it in a for loop for each image file inside your folder variable.

Comment: I tried that too. I stored all the RGB images in an array and then put a loop for each image in the array to call `img.convert('L')` and store each converted image into a new list, and yet I get the same Memory Error, although this time it's worse cause it pushes all the functionalities of my laptop to the edge until the screen goes all blank and I have to forcefully restart the system.

Comment: What is a *"fundus"* image please?

Comment: Why do you want to hold them all in memory at once?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to train on them to get a measure of diabetic retinotherapy, for which I need to hold them in memory at once and send my array for training the model.

Comment: 4000 * 2000 * 3 * 413 is 10gb, and that's if you keep the images as uchar. If you want to have float values, it'll be 40gb. You don't need to show your model the whole training set at the same time.

Comment: @user894763 Yes, I think you are right. Can you suggest me how can I work around the issue then? How can I train on all images without loading them altogether? I'm currently using Keras to build up my CNN model.

Comment: @Prachi As the cause of your problem is found, I suggest you close this question and open up a new question to get the best help.

Comment: You'll need to study the keras docs. Usually you give the model one training dataset at a time, refine the model, and try again. As you train it, the model slowly improves.

Comment: @martineau I want to achieve something exactly like this. I have been looking for a way to do this since yesterday but haven't found anything in PIL that can do that. Could you please tell me how to do this using PIL?

Comment: @preetikamondal: What part of my description was unclear? If you''ve tried to implement something and failed, post a new question and include your code. You can subdivide the image using [`Image.crop()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is not with the commands but with the size of my data. As @user894763 correctly pointed out, my size of data amounts upto 10 GB which is the cause of Memory Error.